# Session management across J2EE app and CQ in tomcat server

Tags: session, tomcat, aem

My J2EE app is already running in tomcat server and i am trying to deploy CQ as war file in the same tomcat container. I know CQ does not support OOTB session management.Would i be able to maintain session between CQ and J2EE app in same Tomcat container? I mean i would want to store some data in session so that i can reuse it when i navigate back and forth between J2EE pages and CQ pages?

Comment: Any response on this ?

Answer (score 0):

afaik cq doesn't use sessions. you can however jet cookies and access those from j2ee and cq pages. is that what you are trying to do?